# Now gets this new Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index

Tags: python

There is similar questions asked but i didnt get it to work. So here goes. (This used to work fine up until recently so I dont know if python update messed this up or not).

"data" is a panda dataFrame.

```
data = data[data['plant name'].notnull()]
data = data[data['plant name'] != '0']
```

When I use my full range of data I get the "Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!". This may be related to several columns having empty names in the excel i read this from (in spyder when I look at the data these have "NaN" for name. I thought this would work as long as I dont have several column name that are the name i'm filtering by (in this case 'plant name'). But if I reduce the data to only onclude the first 3 columns it doesn't give me exception.

The second problem is these 2 lines of code used to remove all rows where the 'plant name' was '0' or empty. They dont do anything anymore (even if i get them to not crash by removing the columns mentioned above).

Thank you!

Comment: For filtering an iterable, you usually use a comprehension, e.g. `data = [datum for datum in data if datum['plant name'].notnull() and datum['plantname'] != '0']`

Comment: Did you mean "datum" or "data" in your code? Anyway, both versions give me: 
    TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str   
Sorry im kind of new to this.